# Integrability of $\frac{|xy|^a}{nz^3}$ over $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<z<\sqrt{n^2-x^2-y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $a>0,$ $$f_a(x,y,z)= \frac{|xy|^a}{nz^3}$$ on $$A_n=\{(x,y,z):\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<z<\sqrt{n^2-x^2-y^2}\}$$

> I want to find all $a>0$ such that $f_a \in L^1(A_n)$ for $n \geq1.$

Looking at the domain of integration I see that $z>0,$ (thus $f_a$ is continuous and hence measurable), and also $n>\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$

Besides this, I have no idea how to visualize $A_n.$

I think this looks like a case where I should pass to cylindrical coordinates, so

$$\int_A f_a=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{2\pi}\ |\cos^at||\sin^at |\ dt\int_0^nr^{2a+1}\ dr\int_r^{\sqrt{(n^2-r^2)}}\frac{1}{z^3} \ dz=...$$
$ |\cos^at||\sin^at|$is bounded on $[0,2\pi]$ for $a>0$ so we do not need to worry about it.

The integral in $z$ gives $$\frac{1}{2(n^2-r^2)}-\frac{1}{2r^2}$$ and so we have
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^n\frac{r^{2a+1}(r^2-(n-r)(n+r))}{(n-r)(n+r)r^2}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^n\frac{r^{2a+1}-r^{2a-1}(n-r)(n+r)}{(n-r)(n+r)}=$$$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^n\frac{r^{2a+1}}{(n-r)(n+r)}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^nr^{2a-1}$$
Now $$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^nr^{2a-1}<+\infty \iff 2a-1\geq-1 \iff a\geq0 $$ so this one is fine;
the other one function is unbounded for $r \to n$ and I have no idea how to treat it.

> I think maybe I made a mistake in choosing the bounds of integration? Because that $n$ both in the function and in the upper bound of integration is causing me problems.

> I would be grateful for both a solution or to know what am I doing wrong with my approach

Comment: I would note the $n$ in the integrand can be ignored.

Comment: Why? For $r \to n$ the function goes to $\infty$ right?

Comment: That's a limit of integration, not the integrand.

Comment: Also you need absolute values around $\cos,\sin $

Comment: What I mean is that the integrand is unbounded in the interval of integration $[0,n]$ because of that $(n-r)$ in the denominator. I don’t understand what you mean by the $n$ the integrand can be ignored

Comment: Oh yes of course you are right. But even with absolute signs the integral in $t$ is OK because is bounded right?

Comment: The integrand is function you're integrating. In the  integrand, the $n$ in $nz^3$ can be ignored. Any simplifying can be useful.

Comment: I already ignored that. But the $n$ doesn’t come from there. It comes from the bounds of integration for the integral in the $z$ variable

Comment: The upper bound of integration for $z$ is $\sqrt{n^2-r^2}$. So maybe I did something wrong with finding the right bounds for integration?